# Switch PHP version on one Apapche server

Tags: php, apache, version

Can somebody tell me if is possible to switch PHP version on my local Apapche via httpd.conf file in Apapche folder? I have this lines related to PHP at the end of httpd.conf

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

LoadModule php7_module "C:/PHP71/php7apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "C:/PHP71/"

#LoadModule php5_module "C:/PHP56/php5apache2_4.dll"
#PHPIniDir "C:/PHP56/"
```

I thought it should be enough to uncomment/comment the lines with the path to PHP folder and restart Apapche. But this only work for  PHP7. PHP5 throws me an error while Apache restart. Can somebody tell me what is the problem with this solution?

Answer (score 2):

Check this link http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/

First of all don't touch you httpd.conf and update you wamp to 3.1 (Check Link)

After that download and install PHP version do you want ( you found that in the same link)

That's should append php version in your current wamp

Finally, you can just switch between them just like that :

[image]